# Is the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\omega(n)}{2^n}$ convergent? $\omega(n)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

By any test known to me  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\omega(n)}{2^n}$$
where $\omega(n)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $n$ must converge. Take that for the average order we have

$$ω(n) \leq \frac{\log(n)}{\log(\log(n))}$$

where approximate equality is reached only for $n$ being primorial, and you have convergence. Or take even simpler $\omega(n) \leq \log_2(n)$, the same conclusion. Yet, Wolfram Alpha using their naming convention $\nu(n)$ is claiming that the series is divergent.

Maybe it is something that I've missed.

[From Wolphram Alpha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcSRm.png)

Comment: Even the weaker, obvious estimate $\omega(n) \leq \log_2 n$ is sufficient to show that $\omega(n)/2^n = O((1 +  \epsilon)^{-n})$ for any small $\epsilon > 0$, so the sum converges.

Comment: Obviously $ 0 \le \omega(n) \le n$ and $\sum n/2^n$ converges. So either Wolphram Alpha is wrong or you made an error using it

Comment: It does look like [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5Bomega%28n%29%2F2%5En%2C%7Bn%2C1%2Cinfinity%7D%5D) confuses itself on this one.

Comment: @anomaly Nei, it is WA that is whacked a bit. Cool. Me not blind, at least not yet.

Comment: @lulu Note that WolframAlpha indicates "Standard computation time exceeded...". Mathematica doesn't indicate the sum diverges, but also doesn't give a result for normal evaluation of the sum, but does give a result for numerical evaluation of the sum, so perhaps WolframAlpha would give a similar result with Pro computation time.

Comment: @StevenClark  sure, but it still declares divergence, which seems like a bug to me.  It would be fine if it admitted it couldn't sort it out in the allotted time.

Comment: @lulu Yes, this would be more desirable.

Answer (score 1):

Question : Let $w(n)$ be the number of prime factors of $n$ . Is the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}w(n)/2^n$$ converges ?

Solution : Since $n$ is a natural number so the number of primes in the interval $[1,n]$ is obviously less than $n$. So the number of prime factors dividing $n$ lies among those primes and hence the number of prime factors of $n$ is less than $n$. So, mathematically $w(n)/n<n/2^n$ which implies $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}w(n)/2^n<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n/2^n$$  -(i)

Claim : The series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n/2^n$$ is convergent.

Proof : We know that for $|x|<1$ we have $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n=x/(1-x)$$ and so we have $$xf'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^n=x/(1-x)^2$$. Now putting $x=1/2$ we have $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n/2^n=2$$ hence the series is convergent and the claim is proved .
Therefore for inequality $(i)$ the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}w(n)/2^n$$ converges and so we are done.

Comment: Adding to that is that $\omega(n)>0$ for $n>1$ making the partial sum increasing, which is implicit in your answer. But still necessary condition all to work properly.